Dialogflow cx livechat with nodejs integration
This isn't a problem, its much of a query. I want to build a landing page live chatbot. Basically i have a nodejs backend with builders and their projects in collections(mongodb). I want to provide them with livechat in their website which utilises the builderId and fetches the projects to display in chatbot. I was thinking of using Dialogflow cx for this, but i dont understand how to do this, do i have to build seperate bots for all builders or can i pass parameters of some sort. I'm new to dailogflow cx.
I was thinking to add builderID in some sort of parameters. But i find it difficult to understand , how would i send them the link to embedd the bot in their website.
Thank you for helping.
